# why jquery click event not bind on button using modular code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why click event is not binded ..here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/k5avjc0d/3/

```
var Shapes;
(function(Shapes) {
    var Btn = (function() {
        function Btn() {
            console.log('====');
        }
        Btn.prototype.clickHandler = function() {
            alert('click');
        };
        Btn.prototype.bindEvent = function() {
            $('#clickMe').on('click', this.clickHandler);
        };
        return Btn;
    })();
    Shapes.Btn = Btn;
})(Shapes || (Shapes = {}));
$(function() {
    b = Shapes.Btn();
    b.bindEvent();
});
```

Comment: This is all you need to bind a click event to element: `$('#clickMe').on('click', clickHandler);` and just define `function clickHandler()`. What's all that other stuff really for?

Comment: You are missing `new` keyword while creating object. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/k5avjc0d/4/)

Comment: Error in fiddle (not yours Rajesh): jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'bindEvent' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindEvent' of undefined